# Facebook post to wall with API: I post Chinese message, but none of the Chinese characters appear correctly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I use PHP language to post Chinese message to my Facebook wall, but the message did't show on wall successfully — the message is garbled.

Please see code below; the PHP page's encoding is UTF-8:

```
function posttofriend($facebook,$friends){
     $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                       array(
                       'message' =>'2012光棍節快樂',
                       'name' => 'I am tiger.',
                       'link' => 'http://www.example.com',  
                       'description'=>'光棍節到了，每逢此時倍思春，朋友安慰拼啤酒，父母親戚忙說媒， 被怕今年守空房，將來必定孫滿堂！今年過節不收禮，收禮只收女朋友',
                       'picture'=>'http://www.example.com/single.jpg'
    )); 

}
```

Now I can see the messages on my wall, but it looks like this:

```
2012�������옷!
I am tiger.
www.example.com
���������ˣ�ÿ���˕r��˼�������Ѱ�οƴơ�ƣ���ĸ�H��æ�fý�� ���½����ؿշ��������ض��O�M�ã������^�����նY���նYֻ��Ů����
```

Comment: I found [here](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=2263324805&topic=2761) that _"text/html; charset=UTF-8" would work, but "text/html; charset=UTF-8;" would not_. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you need, not an expert on encoding but [PHP iconv page](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) this is a way to change the coding, also, did you use existing code or make it all yourself? make sure it is not restricting the encoding somewhere else (in the API for example).